# Yii2: Выбор записей из базы по полю, которое содержит в себе несколько значений

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, activerecord

Есть база `Projects`.

В ней есть поля: `id`, `name`, `partners`, `public`.

Поле `partners` является `string` и содержит данные в таком виде  `["22","46","5","42","34","37","36"]`, эти данные записываются в базу через мультиселект в админке.

Делаю фильтры на фронтенде и возникла проблема с выборкой данных по одному из значений поля `partners`, нужно сделать такой запрос:

```
$model = Project::find()->where(['public'=>1])
                ->andWhere(['partners', '42'])
                ->orderBy('name DESC')->all();
```

В таком виде запрос естественно не проходит, через `LIKE` работает: `->andWhere(['LIKE', 'partners', '42']`, но если значения будут однозначные, то выборка будет неверной.

Подскажите, как правильно сделать выборку по одному из значений данного поля. Возможно данные поля `partners` следует предварительно пропускать через `json_decode`, но как это увязать с запросом к базе?

Comment: Записывая множество значений в одно поле вы нарушаете нормальные формы БД и добавляете себе проблем.

Comment: А для решения задачи копайте в сторону обработки json в mysql в последних версиях вроде что то мелькало

Comment: @fens, а как лучше записывать данные из мультиселекта, для каждого такого поля нужно заводить отдельную таблицу и привязывать данные этого поля через relations?

Comment: по логике да, но раз вы залаете такой вопрос то таких полей у вас много, тогда попробуйте JSON_CONTAINS функция доступная в новых версиях MySQL

Comment: @fens, c MySQL у меня не такие тесные отношения, поэтому я всё-таки нашел вариант через `json_decode`, ниже описал оба получившихся варианта

Answer (score 1):

Не очень красивый, но вполне работоспособный вариант:

```
$partnerId = 42;
$model = Project::find()->where(['public'=>1])
    ->andWhere("(partners LIKE '[\"" . $partnerId . "\",%'
         OR partners LIKE '%,\"" . $partnerId . "\",%'
         OR partners LIKE '%,\"" . $partnerId . "\"]')")
    ->orderBy('name DESC')->all();
```

Comment: Да, спасибо за идею, только такой вариант не очень работает, а если сделать так, то вполне: `$partnerId = 42; $partnerId = '"' . $partnerId . '"';$model = Project::find()->where(['public'=>1])->andWhere(['LIKE', 'partners', $partnerId])`. То есть я беру переменную, оборачиваю её значение в кавычки и ищу, профит!

Answer (score 0):

В итоге получилось 2 решения, на мой взгляд не такие гибкие, но оба работают:

**Первое решение, парсинг поля через `json_decode`:**

```
$projectId = 6;

$model = Project::find()
    ->where(['public'=>1])
    ->orderBy('date_end DESC')->all();

$projects = [];
foreach($model as $project) {
    $partners = json_decode($project->partners);
    foreach ($partners as $partner) {
        if ($partner == $partnerId) {
            $projects[] = $project->attributes;
        }
    }
}
```

**Второе решение, добавление кавычек для более строго поиска через `LIKE`** (спасибо @P.Fateev за идею):

```
$partnerId = 6; // Значение приходит из реквеста, понятное дело, что этой строчки нет в итоге
$partnerId = '"' . $partnerId . '"';
$model = Project::find()
   ->where(['public'=>1])
   ->andWhere(['LIKE', 'partners', $partnerId])
   ->orderBy('date_end DESC')->all();
```

Первое может быть и правильне, но остановился на втором решение, потому что таких параметров несколько и пока багов нет, если возникнут заменю на первое, которое более строго работает и сравнивает значение.